# Create new sql entry with one value being MAX(Column)+1 gives Invalid use of group function

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I want to manually create a ID field where I do MAX + 1, and I want to do it in one QUERY so I am certain 2 entries cant get the same field.

```
        using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjektConStr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Submission (CaseId , SubjectId, CenterId, EmployeeName, Reason, Description, Explanation, Date, Done, ChiefLevel) VALUES (MAX(CaseId)+1, @subject_id, @center_id, @employee_name, @reason, @description, @explanation, @date, @done, @chief)", dbConn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", submission.Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("subject_id", submission.SubjectId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("center_id", submission.CenterId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("employee_name", submission.EmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("reason", submission.Reason);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", submission.Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("explanation", submission.Explanation);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("done", false);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("chief", false);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: You should use an identity field or some other guaranteed unique value. MAX+1 will lead to reuse of deleted values that can easily lead to problems. You may end up with rows that appear related even though they never were meant to be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
          Use subquery to select max and insert a value
```

INSERT INTO Submission (CaseId , SubjectId, CenterId, EmployeeName, Reason, Description, Explanation, Date, Done, ChiefLevel) VALUES (

```
          (1 + coalesce((SELECT max(CaseId) FROM Submission), 0))
```

, @subject_id, @center_id, @employee_name, @reason, @description, @explanation, @date, @done, @chief)

Comment: "contentif" should be CaseId.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Submission 
 (CaseId , SubjectId, CenterId, EmployeeName, Reason, Description, Explanation, 
 Date, Done, ChiefLevel) 
 VALUES ((select MAX(CaseId)+1 from YourTable), 
 @subject_id, @center_id, @employee_name, @reason, @description, @explanation,
 @date, @done, @chief)", dbConn))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a single query, Either you have to fetch the MAX_id and then increment that, and insert or You can make the table as autoincrement, Here you dont have to include the id in the insert query.